# I need to count my perl execution time. But MacOs X Terminal do not generates the output

Tags: macos, for-loop, terminal, echo, x11

But, the program do not recognize the **for** instruction and generates only one output, corresponding to the first program. Neither the **echo** instructions.
What is the problem? I am working on **MacOS X 10.6.8** and i tried execute on Terminal and X11, and isn´t chmod problem...

```
#The code for count perl execution time, for each archive in Prueba Folder. 

#!/bin/bash

FILES= ~/Desktop/ncRNA/Prueba/*

for f in $FILES
do
START =$(date +%s)
echo "Processing $f file..."
perl $f
END =$(date +%s)
DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
date
echo "It was completed"

done

exit
```

## The output:

```
¿Cual fue el tiempo de caida libre?
42
Si el tiempo de caida libre fue de : 42 segundos, entonces
La velocidad en caida libre fue de 412.02 m/s^2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have **space** character before and after the equal sign. Omit any spaces before and after the equal sign when you set a **variable**.

Also put double quotes around the variables which may contains spaces or reserved characters. --> `"$f"` instead of `$f`

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=~/Desktop/dossiereee/*
for f in $FILES
do
    START=$(date +%s)
    echo "Processing $f file..."
    perl "$f"
    END=$(date +%s)
    DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
    echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
    echo "It was completed"
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now, the program runs!